# How can I create a user with Authenticated Website License?

Tags: force.com-sites, user, licenses, user-management, userlicense

I've been reading about SF External users licenses. One of them is **Authenticated Website License**. I can't find it anywhere in my org. [The documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_platformportal.htm&type=5) says that the license is available in Salesforce Classic, but not in all orgs. Do I understand correctly that it was removed some time ago and now supported only in the instances that used it before the removal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Authenticated Website licenses obsolete?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37075/authenticated-website-licenses-obsolete)

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks, I've seen the answer. It has remained me confused, since now, after 7 years, the overview actually lists the license. 
In the answer you reference a [Platfrom Portal] (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=users_license_types_platformportal.htm&type=5&language=en_US) licence, which leads to the Authenticated Website License page I'm talking about. Maybe they renamed it some time ago. But then, the question is the same - if it's listed(=it's actual), how can I get access to it?

Comment: I see that now. It must have confused me, too. Perhaps you're looking for the [High-Volume Community or Site Users](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_about_hvpu.htm&type=5)?

Comment: @sfdcfox I'll take a look, thanks